# Validate XML Element with colon in XSD

Tags: xml, validation, xsd

I try to validate the following XML against a XSD Schema.

```html
<feed xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices" xml:base="mynamespace">
 <id>MySet</id>
 <title type="text">MySet</title>
 <updated>2018-05-14T08:26:35Z</updated>
 <author>
  <name/>
 </author>
 <link href="LIST" rel="self" title="LIST"/>
 <entry>
  <id></id>
  <title type="text">MySet(value1='12345',Value2='001')</title>
  <updated>2018-05-14T08:26:35Z</updated>
  <category term="name.myset" scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme"/>
  <link href="MySet(value1='12345',Value2='001')" rel="self" title=""MySet"/>
  <content type="application/xml">
   <m:properties xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices">
    <d:value1></d:value1>
    <d:value2></d:value2>
   </m:properties>
  </content>
 </entry>
 <link rel="delta" href="MySet?!deltatoken='0050568558461ED895EA10645A3EFAB7_20180514082634'"/>
</feed>
```

XSD Schema:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
xmlns:m="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
targetNamespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" 
version="1.0" elementFormDefault="qualified" 
xml:base="Mynamespace">
 <xsd:import namespace="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace" schemaLocation="http://www.w3.org/2001/03/xml.xsd"/>
 <xsd:element name="feed">
  <xsd:complexType>
   <xsd:sequence>
    <xsd:element name="id"/>
    <xsd:element name="title"/>
    <xsd:element name="updated"/>
    <xsd:element name="author"/>
    <xsd:element name="link"/>
    <xsd:element name="entry" maxOccurs="unbounded">
     <xsd:complexType>
      <xsd:sequence>
       <xsd:element name="id"/>
       <xsd:element name="title"/>
       <xsd:element name="updated"/>
       <xsd:element name="category"/>
       <xsd:element name="link"/>
       <xsd:element name="content">
        <xsd:complexType>
         <xsd:sequence>
          <xsd:element name="m:properties" maxOccurs="unbounded">
           <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence>
             <xsd:element name="Value1" minOccurs="0">
              <xsd:annotation>
               <xsd:documentation>Value1</xsd:documentation>
              </xsd:annotation>
              <xsd:simpleType>
               <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                <xsd:maxLength value="12"/>
               </xsd:restriction>
              </xsd:simpleType>
             </xsd:element>
             <xsd:element name="Value2" minOccurs="0">
              <xsd:annotation>
               <xsd:documentation>Value2</xsd:documentation>
              </xsd:annotation>
              <xsd:simpleType>
               <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                <xsd:maxLength value="12"/>
               </xsd:restriction>
              </xsd:simpleType>
             </xsd:element>
            </xsd:sequence>
           </xsd:complexType>
          </xsd:element>
         </xsd:sequence>
         <xsd:attribute name="type" type="xsd:string"/>
        </xsd:complexType>
       </xsd:element>
      </xsd:sequence>
     </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>
   </xsd:sequence>
   <xsd:attribute ref="xml:base"/>
  </xsd:complexType>
 </xsd:element>
</xsd:schema>
```

The Problem is: I have the elements named "m:properties" and "d:value1". But this is not a valid NCName in xsd. So my xsd Validation fail.

Do someone have an idea how to validate names with colons?
I do not have the possibility to Change the XML Content. I can only Change the xsd Validation file.

Regards

Björn

Comment: I found a solution by myself.
I used https://www.liquid-technologies.com/online-xml-to-xsd-converter to generate a XSD out of my response. After that i was able to understand and implement an own report to generate the xsd